# Can't push the object to the array in Graphql

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I can't push my object of product inside my shopping cart array i don't know what to do.
Anyone knows how to solve this?
I get this error : **Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.addToShopping.**

User Model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cart: {
        type: Array,
    }
});

userSchema.set('toObjenct', { viruals: true });

var Users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = Users;
```

Resolver:

```
addToShopping: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
            const userId = getUserId(context);
            const product = await Products.findById(args.id);
            console.log(product)
            const user = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $push: { cart: product } }, { new: true }).exec()
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
            return user;
        },
```

Schema:

```
type User {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        email: String!
        password: String!
        cart: [Product]!
    }
type Product {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        type: String!
        price: String!
        quantity: String!
    }
```

Comment: did you get any products in product ? like as per your schema your cart value should be an array.

Comment: yes i have and i can create a product individually but i can not connect it to my user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx i found the answer :)

```
addToShopping: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
            const userId = await getUserId(context);
            const product = await Products.findById(args.id);
            const values = {};
            Object.entries(args).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                if (value) {
                    values[key] = value;
                }
            });
            const user = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
                $set: values,
                $push: {
                    cart: {
                        id: args.id,
                        name: product.name,
                        type: product.type,
                        price: product.price,
                        quantity: product.quantity
                    }
                }
            }, {
                new: true,
                safe: true,
                upsert: true
            }).exec()
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
            return user;
```